# Test execution report in HTML format for MonkeyTalk

Tags: automated-testing, action-recording, iphone, monkeytalk

MonkeyTalk provides the functionality of running test suites with Ant.

Reference: [Running Suites With Ant](http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk/documentation/monkeytalk-user-guide/ant)

I wanted to know if it is possible to generate HTML reports of test execution?
I want to generate HTML format test execution reports after executing the test scripts using MonkeyTalk.
I know that it's possible to do this with Ant+Selenium Integration. But i want to try that out for iOS ui automation using MonkeyTalk.

Comment: What does MonkeyTalk provide after test? Any report? If it's so, you may create your custom report (write some custom report generator on your favourite language).

Answer (score 1):

According to the MonkeyTalk website currently they do support HTML reporting.

From [the feature list](https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk/features-benefits):

> HTML, XML, xUnit reporting for tests and suites
>
> MonkeyTalk provides detailed and summary reporting, with screenshots
>   that let you zero in on test failures. Reports come ready-to-view in
>   HTML with complete, step-by-step detail. MonkeyTalk's summary reports
>   are compatible with the popular "xUnit" standards, allowing
>   integration with all popular management tools.

Seems they worked on these features somewhere in 2013 and it seems finished as we speak: https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/content/how-write-passfail-html-report-monkeytalk